# Bass vibration coming from outside

Tags: beginner, acoustics, soundproofing

I have a low bass sound in my house that comes from a hvac from a bakery. It's not very loud but it's very hard not to hear. It's variating depending on external condition (in hot weather it's hell) . The baker doesn't want to do anything. So I wanted to know if bass traps in my house can help reduce this vibration to a more supportable level.
I don't know much about acoustic and I can't find a lot of stuff so I'm trying to ask music specialists here. I just want to know if using bass trap is a waste of time or something I should try.
Of course I would welcome any useful advice or to be redirected to better place to ask^^
And last, English is not my first language so please excuse any error I may have made.
Thanks

Comment: Bass traps help to reduce _resonances_ in a room, but not really to isolate it from the outside...

Comment: So they're not  "[good, good, good, good vibrations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apBWI6xrbLY&t=30s)"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about acoustics and not music.

Comment: I have an answer, but this is best answered on sound.stackexchange.com.  Take a look at [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41272/reduce-bass-through-wall-to-neighbour/41281#41281) -  it is about stopping sound from getting out, rather than from getting in, but the mechanics are the same.

Comment: If you have windows on the opposite side of your place from the air conditioner, and if opening those windows reduces the bass level, then bass traps *might* help. If not, probably not.

Comment: By the definition of bass trap, one may have some affect on your problem, but your question may be better served in another area other than Music.  You are experiencing vibration from an outside source not setting up a room for music production.  Please look over other topic sections for a possible better choice for advice.